# StrictModeError on using upsert with updateOne in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to add a list of users in DB if they do not exist in DB and skip for the ones which already exists, for this, I am using writeMany operation with updateOne and upsert set as true. But it gives me StrictModeError.

Here is the function which creates the insertMany

```
const bulkWriteData = blacklistData.map(value => {
    return {
      updateOne : {
        upsert: true,
        filter : {
          email : value
        },
        update : {
          $set : {
            _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            status : STATUS.BLOCKED,
            createdAt : new Date(),
            updatedAt : new Date()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  await EmailUsers.bulkWrite(bulkWriteData)
```

Here is the EmailUsers Model

```
const mongoose = require('../config/connection')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const validator = require('../utils/validator.util')
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')
const EmailUsers = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: validator.mongooseEmailValidator,
    unique: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['active', 'bounced'],
    required: true,
    default: 'active',
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: () => new Date(),
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: () => new Date(),
  },
  bounceResponse: [
    {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
    },
  ],
})

EmailUsers.index({ email: 1, status: 1 })
EmailUsers.plugin(uniqueValidator, { type: 'mongoose-unique-validator' })

module.exports = mongoose.model('email_users', EmailUsers)
```

This is the validator used for email

```
const mongooseEmailValidator = validate({
  validator: 'matches',
  arguments: constants.regex.email,
  message: 'Email should be a valid email address',
})
```

Here is the array which was sent to bulkwrite

```
[{
    updateOne : {
       upsert : true,
       filter : { email: 'test@gmail.com' },
       update : {
         '$set': {
           _id: 607ec7fd009fc824c5c34b5d,
           status: 'blocked',
           createdAt: 2021-04-20T12:24:29.693Z,
           updatedAt: 2021-04-20T12:24:29.693Z
          }
       }
    }
}]
```

Here is the error

```
error: Path "email" is not in schema, strict mode is `true`, and upsert is `true`. {"trace":"StrictModeError: Path \"email\" is not in schema, strict mode is `true`, and upsert is `true`.\n    at cast
```

This doesn't make sense as I do have email in the schema

**This actually updates the DB with the data and then throws the error.**

What could be the possible solution?

Comment: make sure you are working on same server and you have saved all the files, i have executed your code its working properly to me.

Comment: I have saved all files and using the correct server, but the error still persists. Could you share me your code through mail(sangeethkichu100@gmail.com) or some other source.
And what version of mongoDB are you using?

Comment: i have just created a server file and added your code and executed in nodejs, its same as your code, i have mongodb 4.4. and mongoose 5.10.11

Comment: I am using mongo 4.4.4 and mongoose the same as you, but it still shows the same error. It's throwing the error after it is updated on DB. Any ideas on where else I could have gone wrong or any alternative solutions?

Comment: you just need to debug your problem, i think you missed something or there is some extra things after query, just console `blacklistData` variable is there any extra element for update.